# Why ConcreteObserver holds a reference to ConcreteSubject in Observer Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Consider the diagram below.

### Problem:

At page 294 of the *Design Pattern* book, ***Applicability***'s first item:

> - *When an abstraction has two aspects, one dependent on the other. Encapsulating these aspects in separate objects lets you vary and reuse them independently.*

Q1: If you want to "*vary and reuse them independently*", why did you bind ConcreteObserver to a ConcreteSubject?

No, this is not a question about implementation. When the author designed the diagram, he must had a general object-oriented idea in his mind, and I don't think they didn't notice it will cause coupling between ConcreteSubject and ConcreteObserver.

Q2: What's the purpose of Subject interface? Some books omit it.

No, this is not a question about implementation. I consider it a trade-off - the authors must have some idea about it, so he decide to make an interface for it, regardless that a ConcreteObserver holding a reference of ConcreteSubject means you might not need the interface at all, since you can't change it. But this is just my opinion.

For Q1, I think it's related one of the SOLID principle.
For Q2, I think it is to unify the interface of all *concrete* subjects, but the interface itself won't show in the code.

I need other point of view.

[image: UML of Observer]

Comment: Sorry, `Subject` is not an interface, it is an (abstract) class with some code implementation in it.

Comment: @NghiaBui: But if you think about why Subject is an abstract class, you will find that it's just for reusing the implementation(the *some code* you said), which in my point of view is not very good, and this can be replaced by composition.

Comment: Sometimes Composition is overkill and Inheritance is just fine enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. I believe, "*vary and reuse them independently*," should say that you can vary the *observers* and reuse the *subject*. The inverse doesn't make sense. Page 296 contradicts the diagram.

   > You can reuse subjects without reusing their observers, and vice versa.

   Clearly, you cannot reuse an observer without its subject when there is a direct dependency on the concrete implementation.
2. Code reuse seems like the most obvious purpose for a Subject abstraction; but I could also imagine an application context wiring beans together where different concrete subjects are irrelevant (perhaps because an observer wants notification of all data changes, à la page 297: "*Observing more than one subject.*") In the case where an observer maintains a reference to its subject and registers itself, the Subject abstraction might not be necessary.